# Sitemap or index for each subfolder in project

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have all of my notes organized under one project, "Notes", which consists of multiple subfolders with each subject:

```
|-Notes
  |-Subject 1
    | - topic.org
  |-Subject 2
    | - topic.org
```

Is it possible to generate a sitemap for each folder that only lists the pages in that folder, plus the sitemap for nested/parent folders? An example would be the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/index.html), which does exactly what I would like, except there is no need for next/previous links.

It is possible to change the function that builds the sitemap with `:sitemap-function` in the publishing configuration. Is modifying this property the correct approach?